# Remove/delete models from the end of a Backbone.Collection?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm trying to remove the last 100 models from a collection. Is there an easy way to just slice those off and remove/delete them or do I need to iterate through them and remove them?

Right now i'm doing something like this: (in the collection & coffeescript)

```
for i in [@models.length...@models.length-100]
  @remove @models[i]
```

Answer: (in the collection & coffeescript)

```
@remove @slice(-100)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about `coffeescript` , but you can use a combination of `slice and remove`

```
collection.remove(collection.slice(start,end));
```

Comment: Ah, didn't know slice worked to create a shallow copy. For my exact situation `collection.remove(collection.slice(-100))`. Thanks!